# Scala Regex for less than equal to operator (<=)

Tags: regex, scala, parser-combinators

I am trying to parse an expression with (<, <=, >=, >). All but <= works just fine. Can someone help what could be the issue.
Code:

```
object MyTestParser extends RegexParsers {
  override def skipWhitespace = true

  private val expression: Parser[String] = """[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+""".r

  val operation: Parser[Try[Boolean]] =
    expression ~ ("<" | "<=" | ">=" | ">") ~ expression ^^ {
      case v1 ~ op ~ v2 => for {
        a <- Try(v1.toDouble)
        b <- Try(v2.toDouble)
      } yield op match {
        case "<" => a < b
        case "<=" => a <= b
        case ">" => a > b
        case ">=" => a >= b
      }
  }
}
```

Test:

```
"MyTestParser" should {
    "successfully parse <= condition" in {
      val parser = MyTestParser.parseAll(MyTestParser.operation, "10 <= 20")
      val result = parser match {
        case MyTestParser.Success(s, _) => s.get
        case MyTestParser.Failure(e, _) =>
          println(s"Parsing failed with error: $e")
          false
        case MyTestParser.Error(e, _) =>
          println(s"Parsing error: $e")
          false
      }
      result === true
    }

    "successfully parse >= condition" in {
      val result = MyTestParser.parseAll(MyTestParser.operation, "50 >= 20").get
      result === scala.util.Success(true)
    }
  }
```

Error for <= condition:

```
Parsing failed with error: string matching regex `[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+' expected but `=' found
```

Comment: Try modifying the order of the subpatterns: `expression ~ ( "<=" | ">=" | ">" | "<") ~ expression ^^ {`.

Comment: Thanks! It did work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *change the order of the alternatives* so that the longest options could be checked first.

```
expression ~ ( "<=" | ">=" | ">" | "<") ~ expression ^^ {
```

**If the shortest alternative matches first, others are not considered at all.**

Also note that a period does not have to be escaped inside a character class, this will do:

```
"""[a-zA-Z0-9.]+""".r
```

Comment: Accepted your :), for some reason it was third in the list.

Comment: Thank you, I also added a regex-related comment to the answer itself.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that "<" is matched by <=, so it moves on to trying the expression. If you change the order so that "<=" comes first, that will be matched instead, and you will get the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

@Prateek: it does not work cause the regex engine works just like a boolean OR. It does not search further if one of the patterns in the or-chain is satisfied at a certain point.

So, when use `|` between patterns, *if two or more patterns have substring in common*, **you have to place the longest first**.

As a **general rule**: *order the patterns starting from the longest to the shortest*.

Change the relevant line like this make it works:

```
 // It works as expected with '>= / >' also before for the same reason
 expression ~ ("<=" | "<" | ">=" | ">") ~ expression ^^ {
```

Or you want to follow the *general rule*:

```
 expression ~ ("<=" | ">=" | "<" | ">") ~ expression ^^ {
```